# Join two tables with condition

Tags: mysql, left-join, union

I have to tables and I would like to join them with a SQL-Query. It might be the easiest thing of the world but... well.

Table "count":

```
-----------------------------
¦ id   ¦ segment    ¦ count ¦
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
¦ 1    ¦ fruits     ¦ 0     ¦
-----------------------------
¦ 2    ¦ sweets     ¦ 2     ¦
-----------------------------
```

Table "food":

```
-------------------------------------
¦ id   ¦ type            ¦ segment  ¦ 
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
¦ 1    ¦ banana          ¦ fruits   ¦
-------------------------------------
¦ 2    ¦ cranberries     ¦ fruits   ¦
-------------------------------------
¦ 3    ¦ strawberries    ¦ fruits   ¦
-------------------------------------
¦ 4    ¦ chocolate       ¦ sweets   ¦
-------------------------------------
¦ 5    ¦ candy           ¦ sweets   ¦
-------------------------------------
```

I would like to fill a "foodbox" with fruits and sweets. Only sweets can still be added to the "foodbox" as there are already enough fruits in it.

How can I list just sweets (chocolate and candy) because fruits cannot be added anymore (fruits = 0)?

My query so far:

```
SELECT type.food
FROM count, food 
WHERE type.food LIKE '%$query%' AND segment.food > '1'
```

(The items should be listed after the user typed in the desired item in a searchfield. Therefore I used LIKE.)

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: what is your $query .. ?

Comment: The query comes from a bootstrap typeahead input field. Works like a charm.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT food.type FROM count, food WHERE food.segment = count.segment AND food.type LIKE '%$query%' AND count.count > 0
```

Comment: You are rockstar, drodil! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

When you want to do join then there should be a condition . . and the alias you are using are not correct it should be `food.type` and not `type.food`

since you want to match for the multiple vales LIKE will not hep you .. probable [find_in_set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) is what you want ...

Try this

```
SELECT f.type
FROM count c
join food f 
on c.segment = f.segment 
where  FIND_IN_SET(f.segment, 'sweets,fruit') and c.count >=1
```

see [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25d4b/1)

hope it helps you ..

Comment: Thank you very much. I cannot vote yet so it was not me. Also thank you for going the extra mile and setting up the sqlfiddle! Just starting here, awesome community and quick help!